# how to set scss dynamic class name of margin values

Tags: css, sass

How to set the scss dynamic class name using margin values.
This is what I tried

```
$spaceamounts: (1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140,150,160,170,180,);  
$sides: (top, bottom, left, right);  

@each $space in $spaceamounts {
  @each $side in $sides {
    .m#{str-slice($side, 0, 1)}-#{$space} {
      margin-#{$side}: #{$space}px !important;
    }
    .p#{str-slice($side, 0, 1)}-#{$space} {
      padding-#{$side}: #{$space}px !important;
    }
  }
}
```

So I can use margin/padding class name like pt-1, mt-10

But I want to set the $spaceamounts value as  1~999.

Anyone know how to fix the code?

Comment: Do you want to create a class for **every** value between 1 and 999 ?

Comment: @Amaury Hanser  yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a class for **every** values between 1 and 999, you can get rid of `$spaceamounts` and use a `@for` loop:

```
$sides: (top, bottom, left, right);  

@for $i from 1 through 999 {
  @each $side in $sides {
    .m#{str-slice($side, 0, 1)}-#{$i} {
      margin-#{$side}: #{$i}px !important;
    }
    .p#{str-slice($side, 0, 1)}-#{$i} {
      padding-#{$side}: #{$i}px !important;
    }
  }
}
```

For what it's worth, I think that it's not something you should do as it will generate a massive amount of code.